# Beginner Tic Tac Toe Game for Python

Tags: python, beginner, python-3.x, tic-tac-toe

I am a beginner programmer and would like some feedback on this Tic Tac Toe game I made on Python. Any feedback would be appreciated, as I really want to get better at programming and pick up good habits. Here is my code. Something I would add is `try` statements for invalid user input, but this is not important as I would like feedback on how to optimise this code. I would also love feedback on the `check_if_win()` function as I believe there might be a better way of doing this. Thank you!

```
"""Tic Tac Toe"""

__author__ = "Enrique Gonzalez Aretos"

EMPTY = " "
PLAYER_1 = "X"
PLAYER_2 = "O"

# Create Board
def create_board():
    """
    Function which creates an empty game board
    :return: <list<list<str>>> Returns the game board
    """
    return [
        [EMPTY, EMPTY, EMPTY],
        [EMPTY, EMPTY, EMPTY],
        [EMPTY, EMPTY, EMPTY]
    ]
# Show board
def show_board(board):
    """
    Function which prints the board for the user
    :param board: <list<list<str>>> The Tic Tac Toe board
    :return: <str> A clean-looking version of the board
    """
    for x in board:
        # Find better way to print this
        print("|".join(x))

# Place X on spot
def place_player(board, active_player, row, column):
    """
    Function which places the player into the board
    :param board:
    :param active_player:
    :param row:
    :param column:
    :return:
    """
    if board[row-1][column-1] == EMPTY:
        board[row-1][column-1] = active_player

# Check if someone has won
def check_if_win(board, active_player):
    """
    Function which checks if the active player has won
    :param board: <list<list<str>>> Tic Tac Toe Board
    :param active_player: <str> The current active player
    :return: <bool> Return True or False
    """
    # Making lists which will store the diagonals and columns of baord
    diagonal1 = []
    diagonal2 = []
    column1 = []
    column2 = []
    column3 = []
    # Diagonal counter is used to index the different values in each row
    diagonal_counter = 1
    for row in board:
        # When each row is checked, the different indexes are organised
        # into the column and diagonal lists
        column1.append(row[0])
        column2.append(row[1])
        column3.append(row[2])
        diagonal1.append(row[diagonal_counter-1])
        diagonal2.append(row[-diagonal_counter])
        diagonal_counter += 1
        if "".join(row) == active_player * 3:
            return True

    # If statement which checks if any list is full of the active 
    # player's symbol
    if "".join(column1) == active_player * 3 or "".join(column2) == 
    active_player * 3 or "".join(column3) == active_player * 3:
        return True
    elif "".join(diagonal1) == active_player * 3 or "".join(diagonal2) 
    == active_player * 3:
        return True
    else:
        return False

def swap_player(active_player):
    if active_player == PLAYER_1:
        return PLAYER_2
    else:
        return PLAYER_1


def main():
    # Creates board and assigns starting player
    board = create_board()
    active_player = PLAYER_1
    while True:
        show_board(board)
        # Ask for player input
        row = int(input("\nIt is {}'s turn play. Choose a row (1-3): 
              ".format(active_player)))
        column = int(input("Choose a column: "))
        place_player(board, active_player, row, column)
        # Checks if player has won
        if check_if_win(board, active_player) is True:
            show_board(board)
            print("\n{} won!".format(active_player))
            break
        active_player = swap_player(active_player)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Answer (score 4):

### `create_board()`

You explicitly return a hard-coded board, using 5 lines of code.  This could be written as one line, using list multiplication and list comprehension:

```
return [ [EMPTY]*3 for _ in range(3) ]
```

`[EMPTY]*3` creates a list of 3 `EMPTY` values: `[EMPTY, EMPTY, EMPTY]`, and the outer `[ ... for _ in range(3) ]` repeats that operation 3 times, producing the required board.  (As pointed out in the comments, using list multiplication for the outer loop doesn’t produce 3 unique rows, but 3 references to the same row.)

### `show_board()`

This function does not return anything, so certainly does not `:return: <str> A clean-looking version of the board`

### `place_player()`

Despite the comment above the function, this method can be used to place an `"O"` on a spot on the board.

Suggestion: indicate somehow if the move is invalid (beyond row 1..3 or column 1..3, or if the spot is not empty, such as by raising an exception or returning a success/failure code.

### `check_if_win()`

This function is using `active_player * 3` in a total of six places.  Instead of repeating this expression six times, you could assign the result to a local variable, and test against that variable instead:

```
win_pattern = active_player * 3
# ...
for row in board:
   # ...
   if "".join(row) == win_pattern:
      return True
# ... etc ...
```

But a winning pattern isn't actually a string; it is a list of cells each containing the `active_player` symbol: `['X', 'X', 'X']`.  You've just used `"".join(...)` to convert the list into a string.  Why create the string when you can just check for equality with the list?

```
win_pattern = [ active_player ] * 3
# ...
for row in board:
   # ...
   if row == win_pattern:
       return True

if column1 == win_pattern or column2 == win_pattern or column3 == win_pattern:
    return True
elif diagonal1 == win_pattern or diagonal2 == win_pattern:
    return True
else:
    return False
```

But this code is still quite verbose.  There is a pythonic way of testing if any item in a list of items matches a condition.  It uses the `any(iterable)` call; if any of the iterable items is `True`, the resulting `any(...)` expression evaluates to `True`.  Using this to test for any of the rows of the board matching the `win_pattern` is straight forward:

```
if any(row == win_pattern for row in board):
    return True
```

Your `for row in board:` loop also constructs the `column1`, `column2`, `column3`, `diagonal1` and `diagonal2` lists.  Whenever you have a set of variables with the same prefix name and numeric suffixes, you aught to ask yourself if you could use a list (for example, `column[0]`, `column[1]`, and `column[2]`) or a loop.  Let's start by making a single column in a loop:

```
column = []
for row in board:
    column.append(row[col])
```

If `col` was `0`, this would make your `column1` variable from your code.  List comprehension can reduce this to one line:

```
column = [ row[col] for row in board ]
```

We actually only need the `column` variable for just the test against `win_pattern`, so we could actually eliminate it and perform the test directly:

```
if [ row[col] for row in board ] == win_pattern:
   return True
```

Doing that in a loop, for all 3 `col` values completes the test for a win in any column:

```
for col in range(3):
    if [ row[col] for row in board ] == win_pattern:
       return True
```

But above, we replaced a `for x in y:` and an inner `if condition:` with an `any(...)` statement; we can do the same thing here!

```
if any( [ row[col] for row in board ] == win_pattern for col in range(3)):
    return True
```

We can also do this for the forward diagonal:

```
if [ board[i][i] for i in range(3) ] == win_pattern:
    return True
```

And the reverse diagonal:

```
if [ board[i][2-i] for i in range(3) ] == win_pattern:
    return True
```

This looks a lot shorter, and simpler:

```
win_pattern = [ active_player ] * 3

if any(row == win_pattern for row in board):
    return True

if any( [ row[col] for row in board ] == win_pattern for col in range(3)):
    return True

if [ board[i][i] for i in range(3) ] == win_pattern:
    return True

if [ board[i][2-i] for i in range(3) ] == win_pattern:
    return True

return False
```

... but I don't quite like it yet.  We can get rid of the `win_pattern` list, and all the `[ ... for x in y ]` list creation, using something similar to `any(...)`: the `all(...)` function.  It returns `True` when all elements are `True`.  So instead of

```
if [ row[col] for row in board ] == [ active_player ] * 3:
```

which creates a list of 3 items on the left-hand-side and creates a list of 3 items on the right hand side and tests if the lists are the same, we'll test if the first element on the left-hand-side is the same as the first element on the right-hand-side, and ditto for the second elements, and ditto for the third elements.  Of course, all 3 elements on the right-hand-side are the same element.  So the `all(...)` statement will look like:

```
if all(row[col] == active_player for row in board):
```

Again, that is testing one particular column index: `col`.  If we want to check if any column has the winning pattern, we'll wrap this in an `any` call:

```
if any( all(row[col] == active_player for row in board) for col in range(3)):
    return True
```

So, changing the implementation slightly, to exploit the duality nature of rows and columns, you might write this method as:

```
def check_if_win(board, active_player):

    if any( all(board[r][c] == active_player for c in range(3)) for r in range(3)):
        return True

    if any( all(board[r][c] == active_player for r in range(3)) for c in range(3)):
        return True

    if all(board[i][i] == active_player for i in range(3)):
        return True

    if all(board[i][2-i] == active_player for i in range(3)):
        return True

    return False
```

### `main()`

```
if check_if_win(board, active_player) is True:
```

could be written without the `is True` portion:

```
if check_if_win(board, active_player):
```

Asking for user input, and converting it to an integer `int(input(...))` can lead to `ValueError` if the user enter bad values, such as `"fish"`.  You should check for and catch exceptions.  Moreover, you should range-check the input.  A user could enter `42` `-1` for the row/column.  Finally, the user could enter a valid, legal board position which is already used.  If the user enters bad values (either not valid integers, or out-of-bound values, or already taken locations), the program should complain and ask the user to re-enter the row column input.

**Bug**: Finally, the game could end in a **Tie**, which is currently not handled.

Comment: `[[EMPTY] * 3] * 3` does **not create copies** of the inner list. After `board[0][0] = PLAYER_1` you will end up with `[['X', ' ', ' '], ['X', ' ', ' '], ['X', ' ', ' ']]`.

Comment: @Wombatz D’oh!  I knew that.  I should know better than adding a last second addition to the code review post, especially to the very start of the post no less!